# gh-pages displaying a blank page instead of project page

Tags: reactjs, git, github, github-pages

I'm trying to deploy my first react app and I followed the link below to deploy it on gh-pages. When using Git Bash I didn't get any error message, assuming that it worked. However, when I open the link through settings, it just shows a blank page. What am I doing wrong? Thank you in advance.

Here is the link to my repository: https://zerhar.github.io/todo-app/

Link to how to deploy a react app to Git Hub Pages: https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/deployment#github-pages-https-pagesgithubcom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I "view-source" https://zerhar.github.io/todo-app/ I see that the JavaScript `script` tags are not pointing to the correct path.

For example, here is one of the script tags which links out to [this dead link](https://zerhar.github.io/Zerhar/todo-app/static/js/2.15fea075.chunk.js):

```
<script src="/Zerhar/todo-app/static/js/2.15fea075.chunk.js">
```

It needs to be adjusted, so the link becomes [this](https://zerhar.github.io/todo-app/static/js/2.15fea075.chunk.js):

```
<script src="/todo-app/static/js/2.15fea075.chunk.js">
```

I'm not quite sure where the `script` tags are being setup as I didn't see them listed [here](https://github.com/Zerhar/todo-app/blob/master/public/index.html) but that would be the first thing to try to fix.

Comment: I tried my best to adjust it but, as you said, one cannot find the script tags. I will keep on trying find a way to adjust it.

Comment: I think I finally found an answer to my problem. Apparently the .scss file was the thing that caused my problem. I changed it to a normal .css file and the problem disappeared. Thank you for responding.